# json_decode works on localhost but not on webserver

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have a JS function that passes a json string to a PHP script via GET using JSON.stringify.

The JSON decodes in the PHP end just fine when on my localhost, but as soon as I moved it to my webserver, it stopped working. Further analysis revealed that my webserver was adding `\` (slashes) to the JSON string and according to JSONLint.com, the string with slashes is invalid JSON.

The JSON on my webserver shows up like this:

```
{\"Product\":\"Walnut Pastry\",\"Size\":\"Slice\",\"Quantity\":\"2\",\"Price\":0}
```

Why does this happen on my webserver, and what can I do to escape the strings?
I tried `json_decode(str_replace('/','',$_GET['json']),true);` but that didn't work either

Comment: "/" is different from "\", or just use stripslashes. http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: That is a bad recommendation. The same code executing on a server with magic quotes off will have an undesired effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you have magic quotes on. [Read Magic Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php)

Also you should take note of the warning on the manual page, and then turn it off.